# Is there any property in SharePoint 2007 that stops ASP.NET applications from redirect

Tags: 2007, web-services, redirect

I have setup of SharePoint 2007 with ASP.NET and K2 2003 workflow and few custom web services, when my ASP.NET application tries to create a new site using web services I get following error,

```
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2f_layouts%2feshare2010%2ferror.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

I guess its because when my code tries to create a site and then redirects get this error, I think it could be because sharepoint is stopping my code from redirecting to that new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially fixed problem by removing custom HTTP module that was redirecting pages with error 404 or 403 and got real exception saying that one dll is missing so I put that back and everything working now, not sure why HTTP module was acting like that before need more research.